# How to merge a Dataframe with new column into Hudi table in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-hudi

I have a Hudi table `origin` like :

```
id     a     b 
1     123    321
2     abc    cba
3     456    654
```

And a Dataframe `modification` generated by some other files like:

```
id     a     b      c
1     xxx    xxx    a
3     xxx    xxx    b
```

I want to merge the `modification` into `origin`, including the new column `c` in `modification`. But the `MERGE INTO` query would raise an exception saying `origin` and `modification` have uncompatable columns. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Attaching a link for reference that could help:
`https://hudi.apache.org/docs/schema_evolution/`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).